# Why do we have .iml file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, iml

After googling it I found this

> IML is a module file created by IntelliJ IDEA, an IDE used to develop Java applications. It stores information about a development module, which may be a Java, Plugin, Android, or Maven component; saves the module paths, dependencies, and other settings.

But we already have `Pubspec.yaml` file for dependencies and plugins . So I wanted to know the actual use of `.iml` file in flutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pubspec.yaml` file (Flutter) is used to declare your dependencies, fonts, and assets. After you declare the dependency there, you can then use it in your code.

While the `.iml` file is used for the project structure in IntelliJ IDEA, it is not specific to Flutter. Whenever you have for example an Android native or Java project you will have a `.iml` file in IntelliJ IDEA. Therefore, this file is basically a metadata for IntelliJ IDEA to know how to structure the project and what each folder will be used for, for example:

```
 <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/lib" isTestSource="false" />
 <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/test" isTestSource="true" />
```

Both `.iml` and `idea/` will be generated when you create a Flutter project and both of them are used for IntelliJ IDEA, you shouldn't change anything in  the `.iml` file and you don't have to commit it also since it will generated automatically.

Check also: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/project-structure.html?from=jetbrains.org#library

Answer (score 1):

Short And Simple

---

> IML file stands for IntelliJ IDEA Module, created by an integrated
> development environment (IDE). ... IML file stores information
> concerning development modules like an android, plugin, java, or maven
> component of a java application. It stores modules, paths, types,
> dependencies, and order settings